# How to give gradient color for bar chart and dashed line for background of chart in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, extjs4.1, sencha-charts

can anybody tell How to give gradient color for bar chart and dashed line for background of chart in sencha touch

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gradients are done using the [gradients](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.chart.Chart-cfg-gradients) config parameter to the `Ext.chart.Chart` object.